# Accessing ValidationResult objects after validation in AspNet (Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, .net-core

Suppose I write custom validation for a model by implementing `IValidatableObject` interface:

```
public class MyModel : IValidatableObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (Name == "Foo")
        {
            yield return new CustomValidationResult(42, nameof(Name));
        }
    }
}

public class CustomValidationResult : ValidationResult
{
    public CustomValidationResult(int bar, string memberName) : base("FooBar", new[] { memberName })
    {
        Bar = bar;
    }

    public int Bar { get; private set; }
}
```

Now I would like to access the `CustomValidationResult` object within the controller or from an action filter. For example:

```
public class MyActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid) {
            // How to access the validation result?
            // Specifically, how to get the value '42' from here?
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: So you need to access to that value their? It might exists a better solution if you explain clearly what you attempting to do.

Comment: validation means yes or no. there is no need to pass anything. your data either passes validation or not. why do you need to access anything?

Comment: After binding the model, the error validation results are added to a `ModelStateDictionary` as a key value pair of member name and error message. You could either call `Validate()` on your model again or create a custom implementation of `IModelBinder` to access the validation result directly. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.0

Comment: You are passing "FooBar" as your error message. If you were to change the constructor to put the "42" in place of "Foobar" you could technically use `this.ModelState.Where(t.Value=="42").Select(t=>t.Key).ToList()`. If you just want to return the model state from your controller, the out of the box method is `return this.BadRequest(this.ModelState);`. This will iterate over the dictionary and create a decent response message.

Comment: @AndreiDragotoniu and @CodeNotFound: for example, telling the frontend that a certain form field is invalid due to its length. That is, returning an object such as `{ field: 'x', error: 'TooLong', payload: '100' }`. I do not want to format the error message on the backend, but on the frontend instead :)

Comment: @ATerry, in that spirit I could, actually, pass a JSON-serialized representation of my validation result / payload as the error message, then de-serialize it in the controller / action filter. That is, the error message would be `"{ what: 'FooBar', payload: '42' }"` :)

Comment: @AndreiDragotoniu, validation almost never means just "yes" or "no". Most of the time, one has to say which rule is broken, in which manner, and provide as much details as possible :)

Comment: that's exactly what you get out of the box with validation. the way you asked the question did not relay exactly what you are trying to do. so what you really want is for your validation to return a code rather than a message so that you can get the actual error message from somewhere else.

Comment: I mispoke, the `ModelStateDictionary` is `IReadonlyDictionary<string, ModelStateEntry>`. So it would be more like `this.ModelState.Where(t => t.Value.Errors.Any(x => x.ErrorMessage == "42")).Select(t => t.Key).ToList();`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. By the time you get a `ModelStateDictionary` (`context.ModelState`), your original `ValidationResult` objects are gone. But the core data is still there; it just got transformed. The data from your `ValidationResult` objects are added to the `ModelStateDictionary` via `AddModelError(...)`.

In practice, what you'll see is that each value in `ValidationResult.MemberNames` becomes a `Key` in the dictionary. The `ValidationResult.ErrorMessage` goes into the `ModelStateEntry.ErrorMessage` of one of the `ModelStateEntry` objects in the collection for that `Key`.

So, in other words, if a single error message indicates multiple members, that error message is going to show up multiple times in the dictionary (once for each "member"). And when multiple `ValidationResult` objects specify the same `MemberName`, that single `Key` is going to have multiple errors in its collection.

Back to  your example:

```
public class MyActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid) 
        {
            string errorMsg = context.ModelState[nameof(MyModel.Name)].Errors[0]; // errorMsg will be "FooBar"
            // CustomValidationResult.Bar (42) is inaccessible from here because any original ValidationResult objects are gone.
        }
    }
}
```